# How to view console.log in intellij idea using phonegap

Tags: cordova, console.log

I have installed those plugins

[image]

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false)
var onDeviceReady = function () {
    console.log("console.log works well")
}
```

How can I catch the log message in console?

And what made me feel strangely was phonegap tolded me the console file location 
`'~/Projects/Mine/Test/PhoneGapTry/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log'`
,but I could not find it

Comment: `console.log` doesn't require deviceReady you can ignore it.

Comment: @HardikVaghani Nope, the OP seem to have copy-pasted the code from official source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console :)
`Although the object is in the global scope, features provided by this plugin are not available until after the deviceready event.`

Comment: Eric Gopak is right, thinks for you all

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways:

- One is to run cordova with live-reload server, i.e. `cordova run <your_platform> -l -c`, then the `-c` flag redirects `console.log` messages to your console.
- Another is to use remote debugging via a browser (Safari for iOS apps, Chrome on Android).

Comment: Yes, I run the platforms translated by cordova what are android and ios  dividually in android studio and xcode, it works. Thanks.